# How can i install paramiko module?

Tags: python, cygwin, paramiko

I tried to install paramiko module (with easy_install) on windows but i got following message :

```
GMP or MPIR library not found not building crypto.publickey._fastmath
setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed permission denied
```

I tried install using cygwin but this time paramiko had installed in python of cygwin. I have tried to use this python, program is not running because of it doesnt see my packages. I dont understand its reason. 
Can I install python 2.7 on cygwin and how can i provide to recognise to my packages?
or
Is it possible installing paramiko module directly on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is installing [Active Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) and use PyPM to install Paramiko. No compilation is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Recently, I came across a situation where I had to do some ssh related work on Windows.
Paramiko is a great option and honestly one of the viable options, besides of course, Twisted. I still haven't waded those waters in Windows but a tutorial on that is due in some time ;)

Please keep in mind to ensure you download the relevant versions matching your python installation and Windows version (32 or 64).
This goes without saying that you will need Python to be installed. Check this link: Download Python here

1. Download paramiko for windows. You get the zip file:
   Paramiko for windows
2. To build it you need the dependency package pycrypto. Again keep in mind you will need a matching version of pycrypto for your Python. This is a built version of Windows so no install is required. Check here
3. You could do an easy_install by downloading setuptools but I ran into some issues so I chose to download MinGW tool. This is again an installation and no build is required. Available here
4. Once you have pycrypto and MinGW installed on your windows machine, just browse to the folder where you extracted the paramiko module from the zip file and issue this command:
   python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32 bdist_wininst
   TADA! You are all set to use ssh on your windows machine with Python.

For demo scripts check out the demo folder in paramiko or for documentation here: Click here

Comment: Thank you Anand, i followed this document. i have pycrypto module. but after running this command 'python setup.py install' i'm taking again same error message.

Comment: Link for 3rd Point---http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20110316/

Comment: cc1.exe : unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error : Setup script exited with error : command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

when i run on mingw32, i take this error.

Comment: @selin That flag is cygwin specific. If you are running natively on windows then it won't work.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun i tried with cygwin, result is this error. i'm following these steps but didnt work.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun im trying to work on cygwin python. version of python is 2.6 but i will use 2.7. i installed python 2.7 but still version is 2.6. do you know how can i change new version? i will try to change interpreter cygwin python.exe instead of my python.exe on eclipse.

Comment: @selin it sounds like you are mixing several different environments together. Under cygwin, when you type `python` it follows a symlink(shortcut) to the appropriate interpreter. If you install a new version, the symlink will still point to the old version. Either call the binary itself `python27` or delete the symlink and create a new one pointing to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Active Python and problem is resolved. I followed steps on this blog for installing pycrypto and python :

http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/windows-python-ebooks-and-drm/

Thanks for helps.